# Keeping Link Styling In Gmail

Tags: css, email, gmail, styling

I am coding up an email signature and having a headache getting my mailto links for the email address in the right color in Gmail.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="mailto:bobmail.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #252525; color: #252525 !important;">
    bob@bobmail.com
</a>
```

However when I view the code in Gmail I see the following:

```
<a href="mailto:bobmail.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#252525;color:#252525!important" target="_blank">
</a>
<a href="mailto:bobmail.com" target="_blank">
    bob@bobmail.com
</a>
```

So what it's doing is detecting an email address and creating a new `<a>` link for it, but this new `<a>` tag doesn't have any of the styles the original one did.

How can I keep my links for email addresses the same color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is not actually a problem with the content of the HTML but rather how the HTML is inserted into the mail client as a signature.

Outlook has no way of inserting HTML code or linking from a file, so opening the file in your browser and copy-pasting the result is the only way.

Thunderbird for example, allows you to insert code directly so the links display correctly in all clients.

Hope that saves someone a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try directly copying the *result* of the `HTML` into Gmail? Perhaps I do not fully understand your question, but in the past I have successfully copied the result of the HTML into Gmail and it did correctly set the styles then.

As you can see below my signature has tables and different colored links, all working in Gmail. The same trick applies to iPhone signatures too, see [this post](http://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/setting-html-email-signature-images-iphone/) for a detailed explanation.

[image]